# Getting table data based upon it's join tables data

Tags: mysql, sails.js

I am working on the **sails app** in which i have a **store table**,**address table**,**timing table**. 
In **store table**, i have details of the store e.g. **name**, **description** etc.

this is model for **Store**

```
module.exports = {
        attributes: {
            name:{
                type:'string',
                required:true
            },
            description:{
                type:'string',
                required:true
            },
            has_address:{
                collection:'Timing',
                via:'store_id'
            },
            has_address:{
                collection:'Address',
                via:'store_id'
            }
        }
   };
```

In **address table**, i have fields like **local_address**,**city**,**state**,**country** e.g ('sector 17A','Gurgaon','Haryana','India')

this is model for **Address**

```
module.exports = { 
    attributes: {
        address1:{
            type:'string',
            required:true
        },
        address2:{
            type:'string',
            required:true
        },
        city:{
            type:'string'
        },
        state:{
            type:'string'
        },
        country:{
            type:'string',
            defaultsTo: 'India'
        },
        postalcode:{
            type:'integer'
        },
        store_id:{
            model:'Store'
        }
    }
};
```

In **time table**, i have fields like **day**, **open_time**, **close_time** e.g ('Monday','9:00 AM','6:00 PM')

this is model for **Timing**

```
module.exports = {

    attributes: {
        day:{
            type:'string',
            enum:['Monday','Tuesday','Wednusday','Thursday','Friday','Saturday','Sunday']
        },
        open_time:{
            type:'string'
        },
        close_time:{
            type:'string'
        },
        store_id:{
            model:'Store'
        }
    }
};
```

**Store** table is joined to the **address** and **timing** with **one to many relationship**.

**If I have to find list of  stores opened on Monday,Tuesday of city Delhi,Gurgaon?**

How to get data of a table based upon its populated tables in sails.

Comment: give some more details abt store table

Comment: i have updated the question @MohammedShafeek. I think now you are getting what i am trying to ask?